# Stupid question about a morphism between rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and let $\mathfrak m$ be a maximal ideal of $k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]$. By the weak Nullstellensatz we know that $k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/m\cong k$, so by composition (with the canonical projection) we obtain a morphism of rings $f:k[T_1,\ldots,T_n]\rightarrow k$. I don't understand why in this case we have that $f$ restricted to $k$ is the identity of $k$ and not a generic element of Aut$(k)$.

Comment: Because it is a morphism of $k$-algebras, not merely a ring homomorphism.

Comment: But this happens if the morphism  $\varphi: K\rightarrow K[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/\mathfrak m$ of the Nullstellesatz is exactly the map which endows  $K[T_1,\ldots,T_n]/\mathfrak m$ with the "usual" $K$-algebra structure.  Who ensures this?

Comment: Cosets modulo $\mathfrak m$ do no touch upon elements of $K$, since  $\mathfrak m\cap K=0$  (dont forget $K$ is a field!).

Comment: @Dubious: The usual statement of the Nullstellensatz includes that assertion (that is, it is a statement in the category of $k$-algebras, not just the category of rings).  If it is not stated explicitly in the version you are working with, it should at least be easy to extract from the proof.